# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - not appearing in server application eventviewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, object

I have an ASP.NET web application that calls a webservice.  This web service takes in a Dictionary object (which I've filled with session info) and translates it to XML.The application is working fine (and producing XML) BUT I'm getting this intermittent exception (via email) - and the user is getting an error page - although the app has worked successfully!

Source: GardenWaste

> Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   StackTrace:    at GardenWaste.SignUpSuccess.GWComplete() in
>   C:\Documents and Settings\stevd\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\External Web
>   Apps\GardenWaste\GardenWaste\CardSuccess.aspx.cs:line 63

I'm not sure why is failing at line 63 - this line takes an object from the Session and adds to the Dictionary before passing to the web service . And correct XML is produced (the end of the process)!

There is nothing on the application server log either relating to this exception.  If anyone can shed some light on why this error is occurring that would be great.  I'd be happy to include more code as required.

Here's the code for the method that the exception gets raised on:

```
//This method is called on the Page_Load() event
    public void GWComplete()
        {
            try
            {
                //invokes the webservice
                FocusXMLService.Service1Client client = new FocusXMLService.Service1Client();

                Dictionary<string, string> GWDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                //The Path and Filename used to create the files

                GWDict.Add("File", "E:\\ash\\focus\\objrepos\\1\\Input\\GreenWaste\\GARDENW-EXT" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmmyyyyhhssffff") + ".xml");
                GWDict.Add("SourceName", "FD");

                //This is the line that it suggests there's a failure - although it's produced on the XML!
                GWDict.Add("UniqueReference", Session["UniqueRef"].ToString());

                GWDict.Add("MatterReference", "0001");               
                GWDict.Add("Status", "CURRENT");
                GWDict.Add("Service", "CUSTSERV");
                GWDict.Add("ServiceLevel", "GARDENW");
                GWDict.Add("Category", "GARDENW");
                GWDict.Add("CategoryType", "STARTS");
                GWDict.Add("Description", "Garden Waste Scheme");
                GWDict.Add("LinkedNoteText", "GCCGW");
                GWDict.Add("Title", Session["Title"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("FirstName", Session["FirstName"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("Surname", Session["Surname"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("House", Session["House"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("Street", Session["Street"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("AddressLine2", Session["AddressLine2"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("AddressLine3", Session["AddressLine3"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("PostCode", Session["PostCode"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("MobileNo", Session["MobileNo"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("TelephoneNo", Session["TelephoneNo"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("EmailAddress", Session["EmailAddress"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("AddressLLPGRef", Session["AddressLLPG"].ToString());

                GWDict.Add("GWBENEFIT", Session["GWBENEFIT"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("GWBENREF", Session["GWBENREF"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("GWASSISTED", Session["GWASSISTED"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("GWHAVEBINS", Session["GWHAVEBINS"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("GWHOWMANY", Session["GWHOWMANY"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("GWHOWMANYB", Session["GWHOWMANYB"].ToString());
                GWDict.Add("GWPAYMETH", "[1] Credit / Debit Card");
                GWDict.Add("GWDDINST", "");
                GWDict.Add("GWDDSORT", "");
                GWDict.Add("GWDDACCT", "");
                GWDict.Add("GWDDNAME", "");
                GWDict.Add("GWDDMAND", "");
                GWDict.Add("GWTERMS", "[Y] Yes");

                //sends the Dictionary object to the Web service
                bool success = client.CreateXML(GWDict);
                if (success)
                {

                }
                else
                    {Response.Redirect("Error.aspx", false);}
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Generates an email notification there's a problem
                WebForm_Exceptions.ExceptionNotifier(ex);
            }

            Session.Abandon();
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your line 63 in the question?

Comment: apologies folks, code now added. I've only been using .NET for about 12 months so there's probably some bad examples of code there.